# .then не дожидается ответа от await

Tags: javascript, reactjs

С бд должен прийти пароль, но `then` не дожидается ответа и отправляет пустой `state`. Нужно дождаться, чтобы `state` не был пустым. Как это реализовать?

```
async handleSignIn(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        const email = this.emailInputRef.current.value;
        //const password = this.passwordInputRef.current.value;
        const supabase = createClient(/* строка подключения к бд*/)
        await supabase
        .from('clients')
        .select("*")
        .eq('email', email)
        .then((emailBase)=>{
            ///console.log(emailBase.data)
            this.setState({
                password: emailBase.data[0].password
            })
                bcrypt.compare(this.state.passwordInput, 
                this.state.password, function(err, isMatch){
                if(err)throw err;
                else if(!isMatch)console.log("Password doesn't match!");
                else console.log("Password matches");
            })
        })
    }
```

Comment: Тут, вероятнее, проблема в другом. После вызова `setState` в том же вызове функции `this.state` вернёт прежнее значение, а не обновлённое. Поэтому лучше занести в локальную переменную значение состояние и использовать её.

Comment: `await` должен быть перед `createClient`.

Answer (score 0):

#### В React обновление состояния это асинхронная операция

> Изменение состояния методом **setState** может произойти гораздо позже, чем выполнится следующая строчка кода.

Что бы исправить поведение и не дожидаться обновления состояния компонента, в `.then()` необходимо смотреть на значение которое пришло, а не на то, которое есть в состоянии сейчас

```
async handleSignIn(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    const email = this.emailInputRef.current.value;
    //const password = this.passwordInputRef.current.value;
    const supabase = createClient(/* строка подключения к бд*/)
    await supabase
        .from('clients')
        .select("*")
        .eq('email', email)
        .then((emailBase) => {
            ///console.log(emailBase.data)
            // setState выполнится позже, просто говорим React, что надо обновить состояние компонента
            this.setState({
                password: emailBase.data[0].password
            })
            bcrypt.compare(this.state.passwordInput,
                emailBase.data[0].password, function (err, isMatch) {
                // ^^^^^^ подставляем текущие значение
                    if (err) throw err;
                    else if (!isMatch) console.log("Password doesn't match!");
                    else console.log("Password matches");
                })
        })
}
```